# Python: Why isn't this working?

Tags: python

I am making a game and the board is a 2D Array, I have a procedure to print the maze and each time it prints it it should show an 'X' where the player is standing. The problem is it keeps an 'X' where the player was standing:

```
-1 X -1 -1 
-1 2 3 -1 
-1 -1 4 5 
-1 6 7 -1  
 9 8 -1 a  
 b -1 -1 -1  
 c d -1 -1 
-1 e f -1  
 1 -1 h g

2 X -1 -1 
-1 X 3 -1 
-1 -1 4 5 
-1 6 7 -1 
9 8 -1 a 
b -1 -1 -1 
c d -1 -1 
-1 e f -1 
1 -1 h g
```

There are two 'X's when there should only be one but I don't know why.

```
def printMaze(maze, x, y):
    oldRoom = maze[y][x]
    u = x - 1
    v = y - 1
    maze[v][u] = oldRoom
    maze[y][x] = 'X'
    for i in range(9):
        for z in range(4):
            print str(maze[i][z]).rjust(2),
        print ''
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but may improve readability for people looking at it and trying to figure out a solution.  If you change your print line to be print `str(maze[i][z]).rjust(2)`, the characters should all be aligned in the printed maze.

Comment: @Brien That's perfect thanks, I was gonna look for a way to make it look better after I had it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x and y are the coordinates of the player, then the first thing you do is set oldRoom equal to where the player is. Isn't that where the X is currently?

Instead of shuffling around the values in your maze array, why not just check if the current location you're printing is where the player is, and print the X instead?

```
def printMaze(maze, x, y):
    for i in range(9):
        for z in range(4):
            if i == x and z == y:
                print 'X',
            else:
                print maze[i][z],
        print ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you move from `(0,1)` to `(1,1)` but moving the element at `(1,1)` to `(0,0)`. So you have to give `printMaze` the new and the old position.

```
def printMaze(maze, x, y, old_x, old_y):
    maze[old_y][old_x] = maze[y][x]
    maze[y][x] = 'X'
    for row in maze:
        for cell in row:
            print cell,
        print ''
```

Comment: But old_x(u) and old_y(v) are local variables. They only appear within that procedure. I now understand what's wrong though it will just take a bit to figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you must store the last pos where the "X" was, and then use this last pos to set the `u` and `v` variables.

```
old_x = old_y = None

def printMaze(maze, x, y):
    global old_x, old_y
    if old_x and old_y:
        maze[old_y][old_x] = maze[y][x]
    old_x, old_y = x, y
    maze[y][x] = 'X'
    for i in range(9):
        for z in range(4):
            print maze[i][z],
        print ''
```

Comment: this gives an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: I forgot the global statement (updated). Compared to the accepted answer, i proposed this answer because I thought it was part of your game to move the old value where the X was before, like some  puzzles! Sorry for late response